# Extracting keywords from text in Android

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

Let us say, a user is typing text in an EditText. Now, as the user is typing, I want to extract the keywords from those texts.

For example, if user types- "I am having headache". It should extract "headache" as a keyword.

Please let me know how I can do this efficiently in Android.

Update: I do not know what the keywords are. They have to be extracted from the text which user enters.

Comment: you need a dictionary in a data structure like trie. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should define what you will consider as keywords.

a. A limited list of words which are the keywords.
Or b. A limited list of words which **are not** the keywords.

That list can be in an `ArrayList<String>` in your code.

When the user changes the text in the EditText (see `EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){...})`, you get the text and `split()` it into a `String []` using `space character` as a delimiter. Next search each word in the array in your list (a or b options on top) either to check if they are or not there. When you get a hit you have found a keyword entered by the user.

The resulting keywords can be kept temporarily in another `ArrayList<String>` for you to use them after finishing the scanning of the input.

Note: I have proposed an ArrayList, to keep the list, considering that it won't be a long list. Fo more complex scenarios the list can be kept in HashMap or a TreeMap in the lines of what @Deepakkaku commented for the search to be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two approaches to this problem:

1. Hardcoding the keywords or non-keywords you are interested in. @Juan's answer is the way to go here.
2. Second option is using some machine learnt model, which is what you are looking at, I guess given your machine-learning tag.

Option 1 requires a set of keywords defined ahead of time, which you say you don't have in your question. So this won't work in such a case. So here's a solution for Option 2.

- Create a model.

  - You have to create a dataset of labeled examples.
  - You have to define a vocabulary for your entire dataset.
  - You have to define and train a model. If you have enough data, you can start from scratch. Otherwise, it is recommended to use transfer learning. For example, you can look up NLP models such as word2vec or sentiment analysis online and look up transfer learning. [TF Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/) makes it easy to do transfer learning.
- Once you have trained the model, you have to workout how to convert that model so as to run efficiently on Android for inference. You have choices in Tensorflow-lite, Caffe2, etc. If you use Tensorflow, it is recommended that you convert to Tensorflow Lite for inference for efficiency.
- You have to build your Android app with the appropriate runtime (TFLite, Caffe2, etc.) and bundle the model in. You can use ML Kit to take care of the download for you if you don't want to bundle.
- Add the hooks to model in your activity by listening to changes in your EditText and calling the model inference. You likely want the model interpreter to be loaded ahead of time before the first inference call for efficiency.